# Slow solr indexing with PHP

Tags: php, solr

I am reading a text file with PHP and indexing a document for each line with Apache solr 4.3. It seems very slow, indexing about 70 000 lines in a day. Is this normal or are there any ways to increase indexing performance?

Comment: add some more detial do you mean for each line u r creating seperate document ? explain ur objective with solr schema so we can help

Comment: For your comparison, the solr I use indexed a minimum of 50 millions doc, and it took 8 hours. Under normal case, yours is definitely slow. But you will need to post how you index so that we might be able to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess that you're sending each document to solr. I don't know which php implementation of solr client you use, but in the one which I found [here](http://www.php.net/manual/de/class.solrclient.php), there's a method which sends a collection of solrInputDocuments.

```
 public void SolrClient::addDocuments ( array $docs [, bool $allowDups = false [, int $commitWithin = 0 ]] )
```

Trying sending the solrInputDocuments in a batch of 1000 or a few hundreds, it would be faster that way. Make sure you send it using POST, and again make sure that the server in which you hosted/deployed your Solr can handle big post upload correctly (maxPostSize and uploadTimeout).

If you've done all these already, I don't have any other idea as of right now.

Comment: Thanks.This was very helpful.Indexing in batches took only seconds as compared to a week when each docuyment was indexed separately